# Disk io has been increased after read enabled in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Disk io has been increased after read is enabled.Its a 10 node cluster with RF 3. Also response time also went high. We are using below query to read data. Can someone help to resolve/overcome this issue.

no. of nodes :10
Storage: SSD
OS: Centos 7
Version: 3.10
Reads: 1000/minute

Query:

---

```
SELECT  *  FROM Test.table_A WHERE user_id =  ? AND group_type =  ?   ORDER BY group_type ASC  , action_type ASC  , created_at DESC  LIMIT 500;

SELECT * FROM Test.table_A WHERE user_id = 98765432 AND group_type = abc LIMIT 100;

SELECT * FROM Test.table_A WHERE user_id = 10999222 AND group_type = xyz LIMIT 500;
```

## Schema of that table

```
CREATE TABLE Test.table_A (
    user_id text,
    group_type text,
    action_type text,
    created_at timestamp,
    asset_type text,
    content_type text,
    engage_level text,
    group_id text,
    item_id text,
    item_igs text,
    ui_type text,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, group_type, action_type, created_at)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (group_type ASC, action_type ASC, created_at DESC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = 'User page view activity is maintained in this table'
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.TimeWindowCompactionStrategy', 'compaction_window_size': '3', 'compaction_window_unit': 'DAYS', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4', 'unchecked_tombstone_compaction': 'true'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 1296000
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 86400
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Comment: The TWCS settings look a bit off - 15 days TTL but you are asking for 3 day buckets, so you would have 5 x 3 days buckets. Is the IO drop off constant, or happening due to large compactions?

Comment: io and read response time are high. And could see below from debug log

DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2020-08-27 12:13:54,469 FailureDetector.java:457 - Ignoring interval time of 3000629398 for /xxx.xx.xx.xx
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-08-27 12:13:56,236 NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Some operations were slow, details available at debug level (debug.log)
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-08-27 12:13:56,237 MonitoringTask.java:173 - 309 operations were slow in the last 5001 msecs
SELECT * FROM Test.table_A WHERE user_id = 374 AND group_type = abc LIMIT 100>, time 735 msec - slow timeout 500 msec/cross-node

Comment: Difficult to diagnose - you potentially have large partitions (partition key is just the user_id) and a lot of tombstones from the TWCS and window set up - the scope of diagnosing this is somewhat outside of an SO question. The query being slow is more likely to indicate you are reading too much data due to the model and TWCS setup.

Comment: Thanks for the info. can I decrease the TTL expiry to 2 days. will it help to reduce the iops when read happens

Comment: do i need to change the table design